# Ajax formula runs stops working after 1 line.

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

It is very odd. All the code before and including line 29 works. All code after line 29 doesn't work. I tried lines 30 and 31 on the console and they worked. I tried adding a simple line of code changing the backgroun to red before line 29 and it worked. I put the same line after line 29 and it didn't work.

```
$('#button-shipping-method').live('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=checkout/shipping_method/validate',
        type: 'post',
        data: $('#shipping-method input[type=\'radio\']:checked, #shipping-method textarea'),
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#button-shipping-method').attr('disabled', true);
            $('#button-shipping-method').after('<span class="wait">&nbsp;<img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/loading.gif" alt="" /></span>');
        },  
        complete: function() {
            $('#button-shipping-method').attr('disabled', false);
            $('.wait').remove();
        },          
        success: function(json) {
            $('.warning, .error').remove();
            if (json['redirect']) {
                location = json['redirect'];
            } else if (json['error']) {
                if (json['error']['warning']) {
                    $('#shipping-method .checkout-content').prepend('<div class="warning" style="display: none;">' + json['error']['warning'] + '<img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/close.png" alt="" class="close" /></div>');
                    $('.warning').fadeIn('slow');
                }           
            } else {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'index.php?route=checkout/payment_method',
                    dataType: 'html',
                    success: function(html) {
                        $('#payment-method .checkout-content').html(html); // LINE 29
                        $('#shipping-method .checkout-content').slideUp('slow');
                        $('#payment-method .checkout-content').slideDown('slow');
                        $('#shipping-method .checkout-heading a').remove();
                        $('#payment-method .checkout-heading a').remove();
                        $('#shipping-method .checkout-heading').append('<a><?php echo $text_modify; ?></a>');   
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
                    }
                });                 
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
        }
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Are you talking about between the "slideUp" and "slideDown"?

Comment: Any error in console ?

Comment: Yeah, the slideup and slidedown are not working... and neither any code after line 29

Comment: my guess would be that your selector is returning an empty object, but without seeing the html or knowing any console errors, it's a blind guess

Comment: I am getting this error on the console, but I think its unrelated: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'colorbox'. I am using the colorbox jquery plugin

Comment: Try commenting the lines using colorbox

Comment: This might be because the html return triggers an error. Can you show us the html code that is returned by your ajax call ? Maybe there is some javascript inside it that gives this "Uncaught TypeError"

Comment: I looked into the colorbox error and it turns out the link to the Colorbox JS file was missing from the head. I added the link to the head and that fixed the problem somehow

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your HTML element with `id="shipping-method"` (referenced on line 30) does not exist in the DOM.

Try this to test -- insert at line 30:

```
alert('Line 30');
var test = $('#shipping-method').length;
alert(test);
alert('Line 33');
```

If you are alerted with a `1`, then the element exists; if a zero then the element doesn't exist.

Let us know.

Comment: Put the alert box ahead of line 29 then. If *that* one pops up, then the problem is line 29. Do the same thing I suggested with that line, then. Basically, an alert() box before each line will tell you which line has the problem, and then using the .length method will tell you if that control exists in the DOM at that moment. You can also use Firebug or Chrome Dev Tools (Ctrl + Shift + i and then look on the elements tab) to inspect the DOM and see for yourself. Hopefully it's as simple as a typo...